# Accessing another database user's tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework-core

I am trying to access Oracle database using EF Core 6.
But the database user given to me doesn't have any database table.

Instead I can see and modify another database user's tables via SQL DEVELOPER.

For example;

my user: my user
Other user: IFSAPP

the following query

```
SELECT * FROM IFSAPP.CUSTOMER;
```

While returning me a result,

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;
```

does not return any results.

With EF Core "`SELECT * FROM IFSAPP.CUSTOMER;`" How can I simulate queries with my own user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **synonym** in your own schema (that points to table owned by `ifsapp)`:

```
create synonym customer for ifsapp.customer;
```

(note that DBA will have to grant you privilege to `create synonym`).

---

Or, you can create a **view** to other user's table, e.g.

```
create or replace view customer as
  select * from ifsapp.customer;
```

(as previously, you'll have to be granted the `create view` privilege).

---

Or, you could even create a materialized view, but that's probably a little bit too much in this context.

Comment: Or you can `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("IFSAPP");` / `entity.ToTable("CUSTOMER", "IFSAPP")` in your EF Core model.